# Mailing Template Tables

Tags: mailing

How can I keep the Mailing template (tables) from expanding once sent.  Example:  Everything looks good and formatting is fine when I send from my end but some providers (I think mostly Outlook) is delivered looking extremely wide where you need to scroll over to read.  It doesn't look professional at all!

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to the difference between how email clients and web browsers render HTML.  This [article from Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/the-tyranny-of-tables-why-web-and-email-design-are-so-different) gives a good overview.

There are two solutions:

- Develop emails with email-centric design.  Since Outlook is the worst offender, [design for Outlook](https://emailmonks.com/blog/email-coding/email-rendering-issues-in-outlook-and-hacks/).
- Install the [Mosaico extension](https://civicrm.org/blog/parvez/a-new-beginning-for-civimail).  Its drag-and-drop email template builder takes the guesswork out since the blocks are already Outlook-friendly.